# What is the scope of LoaderManager?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

When creating an Android application using Loaders, should every activity and fragment have its own `LoaderManager`? Or should there only be one `LoaderManager` that the application owns? And lastly, are the "unique IDs" that are used to identify specific `LoaderManager`s visible outside of the class?

Specifically, I'm having trouble deciding which classes in my application should implement the `LoaderCallback<Cursor>` methods (i.e. should each fragment implement these callbacks, or should I have one fragment implement the callbacks and query the results, sending them to other fragments/activities as necessary)?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out! I couldn't find too much information about this online.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`LoaderManger`'s are managed and owned by the activity. You can create the actual loaders in your fragments or the activity, they will be manged by the same `LoaderManager`. Unique ID's are to identify different loaders you might have in the same activitiy. For example ID=0 -> FooLoader, ID=1 -> BarLoader, etc.

Comment: Hey Nikolay, not sure if you'll ever see this... but one question. If `Fragment`s are meant to be designed for re-use (i.e. you don't want to design the `Fragment` for a single specific parent `Activity`), does that mean you don't want to have a specific `Activity` responsible for managing a `Loader` in a `Fragment`? Is it better practice to manage `Loader`s in the `Fragment` so they can be attached to multiple `Activity`s during the application's life cycle?

Comment: The `Activity` doesn't really care about the actual loaders, is just makes sure they are created, initialized, etc. properly. You should implement the `LoaderCallback<?>`'s in the place you are actually using the data. Most probably your `Fragment` classes.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov You say that LoaderManagers are managed and owned by Activity. Does it mean, that there is no possibility to use the same LoaderManager in multiple Activities/Fragments? Or different LoaderManager, but the same Loader. Maybe one can assign it to application context instead of Activity, and just implement LoaderCallbacks?

Comment: You can't really change the `LoaderManager`, just loaders. You can reuse loaders if you make them independent from a particular fragment/activity. You shouldn't assign stuff to application context, since that means it will never be GC-ed (as long as your process is alive).

Comment: @AlexLockwood Thanks a lot, very helpful! And Nikolay too!

Comment: doesn't it mean that you should have a global IDs manager to hold all of loaders, since multiple instances of fragments can be used on multiple/single activities?

Comment: @androiddeveloper just the point that got me to this question it seems to me that if you have an use case in which you have an activity that contains a viewpager with serveral fragments that in turn use loaders to load data then i have to manage the ids in those fragments to be distinct otherwise it lead me to issues

Comment: @forcewill Yes, I assume it can be a bit annoying to manage. Maybe you could put a global singleton counter that increases for every new instance of this class, and when a fragment/activity is about to be destroyed (because of screen rotation, for example), you could store the id of this instance, so that you could manage it again later.